# How to compute number of pandas.DataOffset inside another pandas.DataOffset

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have `o1=pdandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('M')` (a `MonthEnd` object) and `o2=pdandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('Y')` (a `YearEnd` object).

How to compute how many `o1`s there are inside 1 `o2`?

So in my example, I should get the number 12, which means there are 12 `MonthEnd` (`M`) periods in 1 `YearEnd` (`Y` or `A`) period.

Between `Day` (`D`) and `Week` (`W`) I should get the number 7.

Between `QuarterEnd` (`Q`) and `YearEnd` (`Y` or `A`) I should get the number 4.

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a straighforward way, but you could try leveraging `pandas.date_range`:

```
def get_ratio(offset_a, offset_b, rounding=False):
    START = pd.Timestamp.today()    # any random day
    LARGER_OFFSET = offset_a if START+offset_a > START+offset_b else offset_b
    freq_a = pd.date_range(START-LARGER_OFFSET, START+LARGER_OFFSET, 
                           freq=offset_a, closed='left').size
    freq_b = pd.date_range(START-LARGER_OFFSET, START+LARGER_OFFSET, 
                           freq=offset_b, closed='left').size
    return freq_a / freq_b

offset = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset

>>> get_ratio(offset('M'), offset('Y'))
12

>>> get_ratio(offset('Q'), offset('Y'))
4

>>> get_ratio(offset('D'), offset('W'))
7
```

Comment: Pretty smart, the caveat being all offsets have to be smaller than a year (and divide a year, e.g. no 5 months). Maybe you can bypass that by using a range until `max(start + offset_a, start + offset_b)`? Beyond that I think you can drop the rounding and the requirement of passing a smaller on one side and larger on the other.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is for fixed frequencies. Here you can simply use `.nanos`:

```
>>> m = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('5min')
>>> n = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1h')
>>> n.nanos / m.nanos
12.0
```

With non-fixed frequencies, this throws an error:

```
>>> y = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1Y')
>>> y.nanos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx", line 690, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.BaseOffset.nanos.__get__
ValueError: <YearEnd: month=12> is a non-fixed frequency
```

You can always use a specific date to find out what this frequency can convert to as a timedelta:

```
>>> d = pd.Timestamp(0)
>>> (d + y) - d
Timedelta('364 days 00:00:00')
>>> ((d + y) - d).delta
31449600000000000
```

Now of course dividing these nanoseconds obtained that way is not going to give you exact results − by definition of the frequencies being non fixed. However it should be close enough to round:

```
>>> yns = ((d + y) - d).delta
>>> qns = ((d + q) - d).delta
>>> q = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('1Q')
>>> yns / qns
4.089887640449438
>>> round(yns / qns)
4
```

Then you could of course verify that this rounded result holds for your chosen start date:

```
>>> d + q * 4 == d + y
True
```

Of course the choice of the date your use for your computations is important, 4 quarters don’t always match 1 year if you don’t start in january:

```
>>> d = pd.Timestamp('1970-4-01')
>>> d + q * 4 == d + y
False
```

So that’s something to keep in mind if you use for example frequencies of multiple years.

```
def div_offsets(a, b, date=pd.Timestamp(0)):
    ''' Compute pandas dateoffset ratios using nanosecond conversion
    '''
    try:
        return a.nanos / b.nanos
    except ValueError:
        pass
    ans = ((date + a) - date).delta
    bns = ((date + b) - date).delta
    if ans > bns:
       ratio = round(ans / bns)
       assert date + ratio * b == date + a
       return ratio
    else:
       ratio = round(bns / ans)
       assert date + b == date + ratio * a
       return 1 / ratio
```